# WinError 10060 - with timeout and no proxy

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a bot running for a month now...with no problems. Yesterday I started getting WinError 10060 error. It throws the exception when running the following lines:

```
requestUrl = self.bot_url + self.bot_token + '/getUpdates'
requestUrl = requestUrl + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({'offset':offset, 'timeout':timeout})
jsonString = urllib.request.urlopen(requestUrl).read().decode()
```

I use timeout = 100

When I restart the bot everything is fine for a couple of minutes, the bot is responding correctly, but after that it doesn't respond.

I have proxy settings turned off, in case you think that is the problem.

I don't know how to fix this issue (that was a non issue up until yesterday)

Help me... you are my only hope... :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after trying lots of things I finally fixed it (or so it seems). Restarting the computer did not help, so I restarted the modem/router.... and the problem disappeared!

Everything else on the internet worked well, so I didn't think about the modem as the source... but there you go...

Restart your router/modem ladies and gentleman!